# object reference not set error in mvc5

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5

i am using viewmodel to display data from two tables (Eta and Voyage) and i have used viewmodel name as 'EtaVoyage'.The problem is when i use this query, it gives me this error
**Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
var Test = db.Etas.AsEnumerable().Select(v => new EtaVoyage()
        {
            ShippingAgent = v.ShippingAgent,
            VesselInformation = v.VesselInformation,
            Port = v.Port,
            CPort = v.CPort,
            EtaDate = v.EtaDate,
            GoodsCarried = v.VoyageDetails.FirstOrDefault().GoodsCarried,
            VoyagePurpose = v.VoyageDetails.FirstOrDefault().VoyagePurpose
        }).ToList();
        return View(Test);
```

But when i comment the last two fields related to voyagedetails, it is working fine.

```
var Test = db.Etas.AsEnumerable().Select(v => new EtaVoyage()
        {
            ShippingAgent = v.ShippingAgent,
            VesselInformation = v.VesselInformation,
            Port = v.Port,
            CustomPort = v.CustomPort,
            EtaDate = v.EtaDate,
           // GoodsCarried = v.VoyageDetails.FirstOrDefault().GoodsCarried,
          //  VoyagePurpose = v.VoyageDetails.FirstOrDefault().VoyagePurpose
        }).ToList();
        return View(Test);
```

i need to display these two columns too in the index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault()` might return `null`,

> [**Enumerable.FirstOrDefault**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) : Return Value
>
> Type: TSource
>   default(TSource) if source is empty; otherwise, the first element in source.

Use

```
.Select(i=>i.GoodsCarried).FirstOrDefault()
```

---

```
        ....
        GoodsCarried = v.VoyageDetails.Select(i=>i.GoodsCarried).FirstOrDefault(),
        VoyagePurpose = v.VoyageDetails.Select(i=>i.VoyagePurpose).FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: now it doesnt give any error, but the two columns (goodscarried and voyagepurpose) is empty.

Comment: Check what `v.VoyageDetails` contains. If a foreign key referenced table, the referenced collection should contain mapped rows.

Answer (score 0):

The collection `v.VoyageDetails` must not contain any items, and therefore First*OrDefault* is returning the default (null for reference types). You can handle this special case separately, or, since you seem to just be flattening a collection, you can use a null-conditional operator to set `GoodsCarried` and `VoyagePurpose` to null when FirstOrDefault returns null.

```
GoodsCarried = v.VoyageDetails.FirstOrDefault()?.GoodsCarried,
VoyagePurpose = v.VoyageDetails.FirstOrDefault()?.VoyagePurpose
```

Note it is also possible that:

- `v.VoyageDetails` *itself* is null, depending on how your class is initialized and data is loaded. If this is expected, you may need to handle this case as well. Again with the null-conditional operator:

  ```
  GoodsCarried = v.VoyageDetails?.FirstOrDefault()?.GoodsCarried,
  VoyagePurpose = v.VoyageDetails?.FirstOrDefault()?.VoyagePurpose
  ```
- If you are using an ORM such as Entity Framework, the `VoyageDetails` collection is not eagerly loaded, it may simply not be retrieving the data for you. If this applies, you need to explicitly load the data in the collection. In Entity Framework this is done with an `Include` call. Note your `AsEnumerable()` call will stop Linq-To-Sql from optimizing this into a single query, but I assume this is intentional:

  ```
  db.Etas.Include(x => x.VoyageDetails).AsEnumerable().Select(...)
  ```